# Disable jQuery dialog memory

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to create dynamic dialog, with one input field and with some texts. Problem is, that dialog remembers value of old input fields and is not updating them. I created JSfiddle example of my problem. If you click on `<li>` element than dialog will come up. There is one input field, that is changing content of `<li>` element and some pointless text. Problem comes if, when you change content of input field and save it, from this time  is stopped being dynamic and become pure static field. I totally don't understand why. PS Sorry for my bad english

**HTML**

```
 <div id="dialog" title="text">
        <input type="text" id="xxx" value="test">Some text
    </div>
    <ul>
         <li id="menu-item-1">one</li>
         <li id="menu-item-2">two</li>
         <li id="menu-item-3">three</li>
     </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $('#xxx').attr("value", $(this).text());
    $("#dialog").dialog('open').data("opener", this.id);
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Save: function () {
            $('#' + $("#dialog").data("opener")).text($("#xxx").val());
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Storno: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfjhnom7/1/)

Comment: Put it in a form and use `form.reset()` to set everything back to defaults.

Comment: and where to put it? Iam begginer in jQuery :(

Comment: Put it in your code wherever you do `$(this).dialog('close')`.

Comment: Can you put it in my jsfiddle link? I still cant make it work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can easily achieve what you want to achieve by setting the input value with the jquery val() method on the input.

Here is what i mean

Change this

```
$('#xxx').attr("value", $(this).text());
```

to this

```
$('#xxx').val($(this).text());
```

And here is a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gzx3z6e5/

Answer (score 2):

Change the dialog to a `<form>`, then use its `reset()` method.

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $('#xxx').attr("value", $(this).text());
  $("#dialog").dialog('open').data("opener", this.id);
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Save: function() {
      $('#' + $("#dialog").data("opener")).text($("#xxx").val());
      $(this).dialog('close');
      this.reset();
    },
    Storno: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
      this.reset();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form id="dialog" title="text">
  <input type="text" id="xxx" value="test">Some text</form>
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item-1">one</li>
  <li id="menu-item-2">two</li>
  <li id="menu-item-3">three</li>
</ul>
```